# Bar and line chart not working using chart JS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I am trying the make a html report that contain a lot of charts in it.
every chart is working fine
except the one chart Surface Solar Radiation and Sunshine.
I have tried everything debug it and to find the reason of the problem but could not resolve it.

When I  copied that not working chart code into a separate file and tried to run it, it worked perfectly fine, but as soon as i kept it with other chart again it; not working

code is too long, so here is [link of the code doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/101xlt-YSOr9uLUuK-YMb37Y7BXHehDlDsZsRLZWsSts/edit?usp=sharing)

working chart

[image]

As you can see that Surface Solar Radiation and Sunshine chart is not showing and other charts are visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the code
you are using the window.onload = function() two time
you should combine the on load function in a one chart and then use it
it will work